# How to convert decimal time to time in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have decimal time and I am not able to convert into time.

```
DECLARE @hours decimal(5,3) 
SELECT @hours = 20.30 //20 Hrs and 30 mins
```

I need the output in below format

```
 Hours  20.5 AS Time (data type)
```

Below is my code

```
  select cast(hours /24 as datetime)
```

this code gives output as 20.18 Hrs. However I need 20.5 hrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the decimal part does not really represent the decimal portion of the hour, you need to chop if off and process it separately.

In SQL Server 2012:

```
select TIMEFROMPARTS ( floor(hours), 100*(hours - floor(hours)), 0, 0, 0 )
```

Prior to SQL 2012:

```
select cast(cast(floor(hours) as char(2))+':'+cast(floor(100*(hours - floor(hours))) as char(2)) as time)
```